# How to change Mouse event and Keyboard Input In Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

How to change Mouse event and Keyboard Input In Dygraphs.

I want to change the Range selector or X Axis movement to keyboard and mouse combinations

> Range Selector [Drag] --> Shift + Drag
>
> X Axis movement [ Shift + Drag ] --> Ctrl + Drag
>
> BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve custom mouse and keyboard interactions in Dygraphs for range selection and X-axis movement, you can listen for mouse and keyboard events and then handle them accordingly to change the behavior.

```
// Get a reference to your Dygraph instance
const dygraph = new Dygraph(...);

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

let isMouseDown = false;
let isShiftKeyDown = false;
let isCtrlKeyDown = false;
let startX = 0;

// Function to handle mouse down event
function handleMouseDown(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    startX = event.clientX;
  }
}

// Function to handle mouse up event
function handleMouseUp(event) {
  isMouseDown = false;
}

// Function to handle mouse move event
function handleMouseMove(event) {
  if (isMouseDown && isShiftKeyDown) {
    // Handle range selection
    const endX = event.clientX;
    const selectedRange = [startX, endX];
    // Do something with the selected range
  }
}

// Function to handle key down event
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Shift') {
    isShiftKeyDown = true;
  } else if (event.key === 'Control') {
    isCtrlKeyDown = true;
  }
}

// Function to handle key up event
function handleKeyUp(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Shift') {
    isShiftKeyDown = false;
  } else if (event.key === 'Control') {
    isCtrlKeyDown = false;
  }
}
```

You can modify the `handleMouseMove` function to handle `X-axis` movement when the `Ctrl` key is pressed, similar to how range selection is handled with the `Shift` key. Additionally, you can adjust the logic to suit your specific requirements.

Ref: https://dygraphs.com/options.html